# The scripted value is neither an array nor a pointer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to allocate memory for a 2D array of ints such that I can reference it outside of the loop in which the size is determined.  (I have a scope issue because the size of the array isn't fixed.)

So this was the proposed solution, but I am getting the error "The scripted value is neither an array nor a pointer". Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
//M and m are just 2 int numbers
int X = self.create2dArray(M,m);

for(int kk = 0; kk < M; kk++)
{   
for (int kk1 = 0; kk1 < m; kk1++)
        {
//small "x" is an NSMutableArray of NSNumbers.  So I am just running the 2 for loops to fill the whole 2D array
        X[kk][kk1] = [[x objectAtIndex: (kk + kk1 * J)] intValue]; //ERROR Line
        }                   
}

//outside of Main

static inline int **create2dArray(int w, int h)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(int) * 2 + w * sizeof(int *);
    int **arr = malloc(size);
    int *sizes = (int *) arr;
    sizes[0] = w;
    sizes[1] = h; 
    arr = (int **) (sizes + 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = calloc(h, sizeof(**arr));
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that first line should start with `int** X` instead of `int X`

Comment: This fixed my issue.  Seems silly looking back on it.  Its always something subtle that I miss.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your problem may most likely lie within your manually allocating of the memory for the integers. My proposed solution is to just fill it up with random "filler" numbers, for instance: 0. By doing so, you don't risk messing up the allocation process. In addition, it's much easier and it works given you'll be filling it up with integers later on. Hope this helped!